How to change Power BI default navigation as a cascading page navigation?
I am at my wits here, trying to figure out how to get the Power BI default navigation to work as a cascading navigation like the image below. I am sure that this is not the Page Navigation that you can select from the Buttons. If anyone has answers please let me know.

